# Does my solution make sense? Working with promises, timeouts, try/catch

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, race-condition

I would like to find a solution where there are two promises.  The first promise must complete.  The second promise doesn't necessarily have to complete, but the user should not wait for a specific amount of time before a redirect occurs.

I've tried to create the solution and, since I'm new, not sure how to test this code or see if it works.  Really would like to see others opinion on why this code is good or bad and would love to improve.

```
async function apiPromise(url) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const json = response.json(); 
            return {json}
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
}

// promise timeout wrapper race condition
function promiseTimeout(ms, promise) {
    // Create a promise that rejects in <ms> milliseconds
  let timeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let id = setTimeout(() => {
      reject('Timed out in '+ ms + 'ms.')
    }, ms)
  })

  // Returns a race between our timeout and the passed in promise
  return Promise.race([
    promise,
    timeout
  ]).then(result => {
      clearTimeout(id);
      return result
  })
}

// let's assume this runs, componentDidMount
function setup() {
    let promises = [apiPromise('url'), timeoutPromise(5000, apiPromise('url'))]
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(results => {
            // do whatever with the results array
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            console.error(error);
            window.location.href= '/redirect'
        })
}
```

the `apiPromise` function is used to try and fetch a URL.  It resolves if successful but then a catch statement rejects it with a new Error object

the `promiseTimeout` function is use to create a race condition against a given promise and the timeout

the `setup` function is just like a react componentDidMount or just to initiate the code.

In summation I'm unsure if:
1) I wrote the `apiPromise` correctly with a proper try and catch.  Does this make sense?
2) Will my promise.all work as expected where IF the second promise does indeed timeout, the user is redirected?

Comment: classic mistake in that first function ... the Promise constructor anti-patterns ... fetch returns a Promise, don't wrap it in a Promise ... stopped reading right there

Comment: Thank you for the input,  I changed it to where the function just uses a try/catch around in the function where if the fetch is successful the try returns back an object with the data and if it fails the console errors out.  Question: will the catch in my setup function work to where if the second API call does timeout, then the user is redirected?  Sorry - I'm still learning and trying to get better

Comment: Promise.all is all or nothing. It resolves once all promises in the array resolve, or reject as soon as one of them rejects. So if your 2nd promise failed you will get an error. So catch block will be activated.

Comment: @Thuvarakan I've seen posts explaining to make the promise into a pending state and then to see if it will fulfill or reject - they then catch the rejection and then return it to Promise.all in order for it to successfully run certain promises that resolved correctly while others are rejected.  In your experience, does this work well?  If you have multiple requests, do you just chain them (i.e., async await?)

Comment: @Yunjichu Yes, If you handle the errors internally then promise.all will work fine. But in your case, promiseTimeout function is returning the rejection as it. then you need to add a catch state to the return promise and resolve the promise inside the catch. promiseDemo.catch(error => null)

Answer (score 0):

Promise.all() always waits for each promise to return something and if one fails, it will not wait for others to finish, but will throw an error.

What I would do is, set the timeout into the the function that handles fetch() and then destroy it if the fetch finishes in time. Otherwise the redirection will forward the user to where ever. Also in cases the fetch() does finish in time but throws an error, you might want to forward user to a different url, hence the redirect()-function.

```js
async function apiPromse(url) {
  const timeout = timeOut(() => redirect(url), ms);    
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    // Destroy timeout if a response is received, otherwise redirect
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // Redirect to another url in case the fetch() fails
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    redirect(url);
  }
}

function redirect(url) {
  window.location.href(url)
}

async function setup() {
  const apiResult = await this.apiPromise('url');
  // Do Stuff with apiResult
}
```